# Tweaks related to javascript execution in browser

Tags: web-application, xss

Suppose, a filter validates the url, but not the protocol. In that case I can XSS that field with the following payload

```
javascript://%0D%0Aalert(document.domain);//validurl.com
```

*You can paste above payload in chrome URL bar to see that it executes.*

[In above payload `//` comments out code and `%0A` takes the code outside of comment.] Here we have added stuffs **between** protocol and URL to execute xss.

**The problem:**
I am trying to insert an arbitary letter,followed by(`//`),followed by colon(`:`)  **ahead of** protocol (instead of between the protocol and URL as shown in example above) , something like:

```
a://%0Ajavascript:alert(document.domain);
```

But the above payload won't execute in chrome. Is there any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 1):

According to my test, I have found that the payload is valid but is not executing in Chrome. That is because of Chrome's browser based XSS protection. You need to turn it off so it will execute in Chrome. In Google Chrome, some XSS attacks are prevented using this protection. For disabling Google Chrome's XSS protection open it using the flag below:

> googlechrome.exe --disable-xss-auditor

This will disable the XSS auditor of Chrome and the payload will work well.

Comment: I don't think XSS auditor has anything to do with this issue.
Anyway I tried and it doesn't work. Also, since this doesn't work in firefox.